# How to export c++ classes from .dylib or dll to python and other languages

Tags: python, c++, dllimport, dylib, dllexport

i have a created a singleton class in c++ and generated it has a library. How do i export that singleton class into python using dll or dylib with respect to OS.This dll or dylib can be used by any c++ projects but not able to export to other languages.

As i have observed that for c functions ,we can add MACRO behind function declaration and export it.But how to export classes in that case , what will be the syntax?
we can use ctypes in python to find dynamic libraries. But using ctypes i am only able to export functions and not able to export classes and not even sure about the syntax for that.

I have used

## define LIBRARY_API extern "C" **attribute** ((visibility ("default")))

to export functions for mac and linux and similarly for windows i have used:

## define LIBRARY_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

But using these i am not able to export classes. Please can anyone give a nice explination of these work or can provide good links to refer above topic.

I have tried my best to explain my doubt, Please can anybody help?

Comment: You need to expose plain functions rather than classes

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan if i try to expose just functions and add MACRO behind the datatype of the function. It is building fine, but not able to use it in python through dll.